# Railguns vs coilguns in the field

Tags: warfare, weapons, electromagnetism, railguns, coilguns

I am developing a sci fi mod for a game called armored brigade and a faction present in this mod will use either railguns or coilguns as crew served anti armor weapons similar in form to something like an M40 recoilless rifle or SPG-9.

Assuming that the material and power generation technology exists to power these weapons in a relatively small package; which method would be best suited for operation by soldiers in field conditions?

Comment: @Tortliena It definitely helps, however this answer was made 6 years ago. I’m looking for an updated answer since I’m not sure how our understanding of the technology has changed since then and now.

Comment: Your best bet is to bounty the other one to draw attention to it rather than duplication.